# Slider not keep on moving with onProgress method in react native

Tags: react-native, slider, audio-streaming

I am playing some audio files in react native. For progress of the audio file (Duration), I am showing slider for status of the audio file and for forward and reverse the duration.

But, According to audio duration, It is not keep on moving the position (like timer).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider

```
getInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const info = await SoundPlayer.getInfo();
      // console.log('getInfo', info); // {duration: 12.416, currentTime: 7.691}
      const currentTime = get(info, 'currentTime');
      this.setState({ currentDuration: currentTime });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('There is no song playing', e);
    }
  }
         getProgress = (e) => {
           console.log('getProgress calling');
           this.getInfo();
           this.setState({
            currentTime: this.state.currentDuration,
           });
         }

                <Slider
                  maximumValue={parseFloat(totalLength)}
                  minimumTrackTintColor="color"
                  maximumTractTintColor="color"
                  step={1}
                  value={currentTime}
                  onSlidingComplete={value => this.onValueChange(value)}
                  style={styles.slider}
                  thumbTintColor="red"
                  trackLength={parseFloat(totalLength)}
                // onSlidingStart={() => this.setState({ paused: true })}
                  currentPosition={currentTime}
                  onProgress={e => this.getProgress(e)}
                />
```

It has to move slider value automatically according to audio duration

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should use react-native-slider component for showing the progress of audio track.
Github: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But, User has to move forward/back the slider according to that I am seeking audio duration. In above suggested library doesn't have thumb.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a counter to update the progress bar each second

```
timer = null;

durationCounter = () => {
  this.timer = setInterval(async () => {
    const info = await SoundPlayer.getInfo();
    this.setState({
      currentTime: info.currentTime
    });
  }, 1000);
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  SoundPlayer.onFinishedLoading(async success => {
    this.durationCounter();
  });
}


componentWillMount = () => {
  this.timer && clearInterval(this.timer);
};
```

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative glad you've managed to get it to work.